# pymssql create transaction with name

Tags: python, sql-server, database, pymssql

I'm trying to create a transaction with name. Possibly to rollback at later point.

```
pid = os.getpid()
cursor.execute("BEGIN TRAN trans{0}".format(pid))
cursor.execute("ROLLBACK TRAN trans{0}".format(pid))
```

When I write the code like above, its raising the below error:

```
pymssql.OperationalError: (6401, 'Cannot roll back trans5713. 
No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.DB-Lib error 
message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: 
Check messages from the SQL Server\n')
```

But, when I remove the name part `tran{0}`, it's not raising any error.

1. How should I create a transaction in pymssql. I understand, when I make a connection, it comes under transaction. But, I want the transaction to be named!

Comment: have you tried setting connection.autocommit() to False?

Comment: its by default false

Comment: Yes, I have seen it in documentation. As your examples was quiet minimal I wanted to ensure it's really like this.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do it by SQL. Just use functions in Class Connection, i.e. Connection.rollback() and Connection.commit().

http://pymssql.org/en/stable/ref/pymssql.html#connection-object-methods